# Explain item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks, key, higher-order-functions

```
const listItems = items.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item
    )
```

Especially what is the difference between item.id and id? and why use `: item` at the end?

Full code below, Note that the code isn't something I'm working on, it is a tutorial and there is still more to code

```
import React from "react";
import { useState } from "react";
import { FaTrashAlt } from "react-icons/fa";

const Content = () => {
  const [items, setItems] = useState([
    {
      id: 1,
      checked: false,
      item: "One half bag of cocoa covered",
    },
    {
      id: 2,
      checked: false,
      item: "Item 2",
    },
    {
      id: 3,
      checked: false,
      item: "Item 3",
    },
  ]);

  const handleCheck = (id) => {
    console.log(`key: ${id}`);
    const listItems = items.map((item) =>
      item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item
    );
    setItems(listItems);
    localStorage.setItem("shoppinglist", JSON.stringify(listItems));
  };

  return (
    <main>
      <main>
        <ul>
          {items.map((item) => (
            <li className="item" key={item.id}>
              <input
                type="checkbox"
                onChange={() => handleCheck(item.id)}
                checked={item.checked}
              />
              <label
                style={item.checked ? { color: "red" } : { color: "green" }}
                onClick={() => handleCheck(item.id)}
              >
                {item.item}
              </label>
              {/* <button>Delete</button> */}
              <FaTrashAlt
                onClick={() => handleCheck(item.id)}
                role="button"
                tabIndex="0"
              />
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </main>
    </main>
  );
};

export default Content;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`items.map(item => )` is mapping over an array of items, item is the object of the current item being mapped

id is the id that comes from handleCheck function(triggered onClick), which is the id of the clicked item, while item.id is the id of the current item from the array of objects

`item.id === id ? { ...item, checked: !item.checked } : item` uses the ternary operator which is a shorthand if/else to check if the id of the current item is the same as the id of the clicked item

if it is(true) it adds to the current item object `checked: !item.checked`, if it isn't(false) it returns the item object as it is

Comment: What are some circumstances where `item.id !== id ?`

Comment: Ah got it, The !== is used when we want to delete the clicked item and list the rest

Answer (score 1):

Here this code trying to keep `items` array immutable,if you change `item.checked` value  it without using
It will modify `items` array too

`{ ...item, checked: !item.checked }`

And Id is used to collect only particular item and modifications of it.

Answer (score 1):

The map function iterates through all the items in a list. Each item has an `id`, which is the `list.id` variable. The function takes `id` as a param.

Then if `item.id` equals the passed in `id`, a modified item will be returned. If not, the iten is returned unmodified. That's what `:item` at the end is for.

Answer (score 1):

A few basics to start since I'm not sure where the confusion lies:

- map() takes the contents of a list and returns another list / array
  based on those concepts. e.g. `[1,2,3].map(x => x *2)` will return `[ 2, 4, 6 ]`
- The ternary ?: operator takes three args (hence the name) If the
  first is true, returns the second, otherwise the third
  e.g. `true ? 'yes' : 'no'`  returns `'yes'`
- The spread operator populates one object with the contents of
  another. e.g. If `a = { foo: 'Hello' }` then
  `{ ...a, bar: 'World' }` means `{ foo: 'Hello', bar: 'World' }`

So your example takes the first list and If the ID matches the checkbox ID being targetted, it returns a new object with the state flipped, otherwise it returns the original object.

The net effect is a list of IDs with the "checked" status flipped on one of the items. Make sense?

Comment: What are the circumstances where `item.id !== id ?` Like I can only imagine `item.id` always being equal to `id`

Comment: Ah got it, The !== is used when we want to delete the clicked item and list the rest